# Simple precision issue

Tags: numerics, arbitrary-precision

Considering binomial expansion

$1 = (p+(1-p))^n =
\sum_{k=0}^n p^n (1-p)^{n-k},$

which is true for any real value of $p$, I'm getting diverging results when I numerically evaluate the above even with very high precision. The code I use is a simple one, say for $n=50$ and $p=10$:

```
SetPrecision[Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1. - p)^(n - k) /. 
{n -> 50., p -> 10.}, {k,0., 50.}], 1000] // N
```

For the above computation, each $p^k$ requires at most 50 digits of precision, and same with $(1-p)^k$ and $\binom{n}{k}$ which is at most $2^n$, so in total a couple of hundred digits should be plenty but even with 1000 digits I'm getting $-1.48779 \times 10^{49}$ instead of 1. What am I doing wrong, and how can I change my code to get the correct result 1?

Comment: The computation as written is done at machine precision, before `SetPrecision` is applied. Compare with `bsum[n_, p_] := Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}]` and evaluating `bsum[50, 10]`, `bsum[50, 10.]` and `bsum[50, SetPrecision[10, 80]]`.

Comment: Thanks, but your example evaluates the sum symbolically to 1 and then applies the parameters (doing nothing). I gave this example to make a point for a much more complex one (that cannot be done symbolically but suffers from the same precision issue as the one I gave). Could you write an example that indeed forces Mathematica to use numerical computation but also gives the correct answer 1.0000? Thanks!

Comment: I think the result of `bsum[50, 10.]` shows there is no such thing as first evaluating the sum symbolically to 1...

Comment: Yes, seems so. I'll try this trick on the more complex calculation and see if it still gives nonsense. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: ``Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1.`100 - p)^(n - k) /. {n -> 50.`100, p -> 10.`100}, {k, 0, 50.`100}]`` -- Or ``Hold[Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1. - p)^(n - k) /. {n -> 50., p -> 10.}, {k, 0., 50.}]] /. {x_Real /; x != 0 :> SetPrecision[x, 100], z_ /; z == 0 -> 0} // ReleaseHold``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get high procession results when every number in the computation is a high-precison inexact number or is exact. If even one machine precision number, such as 1., gets included, the whole computation gets reduced to machine precision. So try this

```
With[{pr = 50}, 
  N[Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) /. {n -> 50, p -> 10}, {k, 0, 50}], pr]]
```

or better yet

```
With[{pr = 50}, N[Sum[Binomial[50, k] 10^k (1 - 10)^(50 - k), {k, 0, 50}], pr]]
```

Both give

> 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Thanks. To make sure that Mathematica doesn't "cheat" by symbolically evaluating the sum to the exact value 1 and then numerically estimate just 1, I tried to change 1-p to something like SetPrecision[1, 500] - p. Seems to work.